# Result of @babel/parser and @babel/generator are different

Tags: babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, babel-parser

I take a simple code: "const Component = () => (123)"
convert it to ast, then convert it back to code without any changes

i expect the incoming and outgoing code to be the same, but you can see the difference in the brackets and the semicolon:
"const Component = () => (123)" and "const Component = () => 123;"

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser');
const generator = require('@babel/generator').default;

const incomingCode = "const Component = () => (<div>123</div>)"

// parse to ast
const ast = parse(
  incomingCode,
  { sourceType: "module", plugins: ['jsx', 'typescript'] }
);

// try to convert it back
const outputCode = generator(ast, { retainLines: true }).code;

console.log(incomingCode);
// const Component = () => (<div>123</div>)

console.log(outputCode);
// const Component = () => <div>123</div>;
```

Comment: These two snippets are parsed into the same AST, the latter represents default "canonical" shape from this parser's POV. You cannot retain source code exact after AST conversion, similarly to how comments are stripped.

Comment: it's a pity, however, thank you for the clarification

Comment: Consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/recast (it's recommended by Babel team in an issue similar to yours [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10674)).

Comment: Thank you so much! i will try "recast" on my project instead @babel/parser' and '@babel/generator'